# rank of variance matrix of random vector is less than dimension of vector

Tags: statistics

Let's say $X$ is a $p$-dimensional random vector and rank of $\mbox{Var} (X)$ is some $m < p$. Show that in this case random vector $X$ with probability $1$ lies in some space of dimension $m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$V(X)$ is symmetric so there exists some orthogonal matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $V(X) = PDP^T$, with $D$ having $p-m$ zeros on its diagonal (say, the last $p-m$ diagonal entries)
Now let $X'=P^TX$ (it's our random vector expressed in the new basis). We see that $V(X') = D$, which means that the last $p-m$ components of $X'$ have a variance of $0$. So $X$ lies in the space generated by the $m$ first columns of $P$.

Comment: This is very helpful!